# Expand vertically a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div container, inside there are 3 div elements, each with their own content.
The container is horizontally centered. I would like the three elements div fit the container's height.

```
<body>
    <div id="Container">
        <div id="A"><P>Some multiROW<br>content</P></div>
        <div id="B">single row content</div>
        <div id="C"><P>Some multiROW<br>content</P></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pg28uLcz/)

In the example, the middle cyano element should have the same height as other divs. The content should vertically centered too. How can I get it?

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Also, don't use collaboration when linking to JSFiddle; among other things it just confuses matters more. (Nobody can be sure how your code looked in the first place..)

Comment: Sorry for collaboration, is it a new feauture? how to disable it???

Comment: Don't click the 'Collaboration' button. Click 'Save' and share the URL in your address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/5161/

```
#Container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    display:table;
}

#A {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: right;
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
}

#B {
    width: 70%;

    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: inherit;
     display:table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

#C {
    width: 15%;

    text-align: left;
    background-color: yellow;
     display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: for vertically align there are many ways but if u want to make height same as other div then this will be the good one

Answer (score 1):

How about the following: http://jsfiddle.net/7ecm7qzh/

(using table-cell as display property, with middle vertical alignment, and 100% height)

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="A"><P>Some multiROW<br>content</P></div>
    <div id="B">single row content</div>
    <div id="C"><P>Some multiROW<br>content</P></div>
</div>

#Container {
width: 50%;
margin: auto;
display:table;
}

#Container div{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}

#A {
    width: 15%;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: red;
}

#B {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#C {
    width: 15%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#Container {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#A {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}

#B {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;

}

#C {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

Reference : http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: why that v-margin? I don't want a full page div!

Comment: that margin will match the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this...

```
height:auto;
```

This will make the container set its height automatically, no matter how many DIV's are there in it...

:::::::::::::: EDIT ::::::::::::

```
<style type="text/css">
#container{width:1000px;height:auto;background-color:#CCCCCC;}
#A{width:900px;height:300px;background-color:#00FF00;}
#B{width:900px;height:100px;background-color:#99FFFF;}
#C{width:900px;height:400px;background-color:#CC99FF;}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried without successfull, can you show it in my example?

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#container{width:1000px;height:auto;background-color:#CCCCCC;}
#A{width:900px;height:300px;background-color:#00FF00;}
#B{width:900px;height:100px;background-color:#99FFFF;}
#C{width:900px;height:400px;background-color:#CC99FF;}
</style>
I used background-color just to show the difference...

Comment: But I don't know the heights, content is dynamically provided.

Comment: I've provided the heights just for demonstration.. You can apply your own height.. or you can even give their height as AUTO if you want... then the height will be automatically adjusted according to your content..

Comment: But that's the question! I need the same unknown height for A,B and C divs.